# Reading/writing QObjects

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I *think* I can write a `QObject` like this by taking advantage of the `Q_PROPERTY`s:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &ds, const Object &obj) {
    for(int i=0; i<obj.metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        if(obj.metaObject()->property(i).isStored(&obj)) {
            ds << obj.metaObject()->property(i).read(&obj);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Which, if that's true, I don't know why `QObject`s don't already have that method implemented because it's pretty generic. But that's besides the point. How would I read the file? i.e., implement this function?

```
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &ds, Object &obj) {
    return ds;
}
```

I'm thinking I can somehow use `ds.readBytes` but how would I get the length of the property?

**PS:** If it wasn't obvious, `Object` is my custom class that inherits from `QObject`.

Comment: I don't think QObjects are supposed to be serializable. You can't even copy them. As for reading QVariant back, it is either very easy (just read it with >> into empty QVariant), or hard -- you must handle type and length yourself.

Comment: If you are looking for serialization, you might want to look at Boost.Serialize.

Comment: @Eugene: Should have posted that as an answer... for some reason it didn't occur to me that I could just read in the `QVariant`. I figured they'd be all different sizes or something, but that's not how C++ works.

Comment: Oh, they all are different sizes. But I think QVariant writes out its type and length, besides data itself. Just enough to read it back.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was some big union mess internally... which means it would be the size of the largest element, no? (+ the type info of course). Anyway, it doesn't really matter. They're readable and writable :)

Comment: Heh, imagine QString in a union :)

Comment: "The QVariant class acts like a union for the most common Qt data types." - Oh.. I guess that's where I got that idea from. What are they using then, void pointers? And what's wrong with a QString in a union... it's just a char pointer or something isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &ds, Object &obj) {
    QVariant var;
    for(int i=0; i<obj.metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        if(obj.metaObject()->property(i).isStored(&obj)) {
            ds >> var;
            obj.metaObject()->property(i).write(&obj, var);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Thanks to [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114488/eugene).